# 'Tree-like' dropdown list traversing ForeignKeys in Django

Tags: python, django

I have some models of the form:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=400)

class PollChoice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class PollVote(models.Model):
    poll_choice = models.OneToOneField(PollChoice)
    weight = models.IntegerField()
```

Let's say I have two Poll objects with different questions (e.g. "Do you like pineapples?" and "Did you suck your thumb as a child?"), each with 'Yes' and 'No' PollChoices. Currently, if I try and create a new PollVote object in the admin, the PollChoice drop-down will greet me with the following choices:

```
Yes
No
Yes
No
```

This doesn't tell me which Poll I'd be applying my vote to. Is there a way to create a drop-down of this form instead?

```
<Do you like pineapples?>
    Yes
    No
<Did you suck your thumb as a child?>
    Yes
    No
```

The entries in angle brackets would ideally not be selectable, and only serve to disambiguate the PollChoice I'd be selecting. I'm open to including additional apps if need be as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to render to HTML based on your model structure? It can be done with [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). Here's example:
View:

```
polls = Poll.objects.select_related('pollchoice__poll').all()
return render(request, 'test_poll.html', {'polls': polls})
```

Template:

```
<form>
    {% for poll in polls %}
        <p>&lt;{{ poll.question_text }}&gt;</p>
        {% for pollchoice in poll.pollchoice_set.all %}
            <input type="radio" name="question_{{poll.id}}" value="choice_{{pollchoice.id}}"> {{pollchoice.choice_text}} <br/>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```